# Characteristic function of randomly sampled process

Tags: stochastic-processes, characteristic-functions, stopping-times

Let $Y_t$ be a continuous time stochastic process with characteristic function

$$
\varphi_{Y_t}\left(\omega\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{i\,\omega\,Y_t}\right].
$$

For all $t$ let $\tau_t$ be a stopping time with density $f_t\left(z\right)$. I need to calculate the characteristic function of $Y_{\tau_t}$, that is of the process $Y$ randomly sampled at $\tau_t$. My guess is

$$
\varphi_{Y_{\tau_t}}=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{i\,\omega\,Y_{\tau_t}}\right] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi_{Y_z}\left(\omega\right)\,f_t\left(z\right)\,dz
$$

am I right? It seems quite intuitive to me but I miss a formal justification.

Comment: If $\tau$ with PDF $f$ is independent of the process $(Y_t)$ then $$E(u(Y_\tau))=\int_0^\infty E(u(Y_t))\,f(t)\,dt$$ Let me suggest to (add the independence hypothesis and) use this for $$u(y)=e^{i\omega y}$$